# Android Studio Volley Login and Save Login Info

Tags: java, php

does anyone know how to save user login information? So when user close the application and then they open it again, they don't have to login again. I'm using volley library for my application.

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` to save users information .

Comment: How to use Shared Preferenses? I'm newbe to Android Studio

Comment: @Ghifari You can check out  [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) for example